# What does a hash/pound (#) represent in a format string?

Tags: objective-c, string, formatting

I have some code to format a file size string:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat: @"#,##0.## bytes"];
```

Is the `@"#,##0.## bytes"` the same kind of format string as I'd use in stringWithFormat? What do the hash/pound symbols mean here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

# will usually be replaced by a number if one exists, and nothing if it doesn't.
0 will be replaced by a number if one exists, and zero if it does not.

So for the following formatting '##00.00##' you would get the following outputs:

```
1 => 01.00
12.1 => 12.10
1234.5 => 1234.50
1.2345 => 01.2345
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the examples, they cleared things up for me.

Answer (score 4):

They are called placeholders.

> Placeholders
>
> You use the pound sign character (#)
>   to represent numeric characters that
>   will be input by the user. For
>   example, for the positive pattern
>   "$#,##0.00", if the characters 76329
>   were entered into a cell to which the
>   pattern has been applied, they would
>   be displayed as $76,329.00. Strictly
>   speaking, however, you don't need to
>   use placeholders. The format strings
>   ",0.00", "#,#0.00", and "#,##0.00" are
>   functionally equivalent. In other
>   words, including separator characters
>   in a pattern string signals
>   NSNumberFormatter to use the
>   separators, regardless of whether you
>   use (or where you put) placeholders.
>   The placeholder character's chief
>   virtue lies in its ability to make
>   pattern strings more human-readable,
>   which is especially useful for
>   displaying patterns in the user
>   interface.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/InternetWeb/Reference/WO542Reference/com/webobjects/foundation/NSNumberFormatter.html

Answer (score 3):

'#' represents an optional digit place that will not appear in case of a 0 digit in that position, whereas 0 means the digit will always appear.

Let's take `345.5` as an example:

```
#,##0.## = 345.5
0,000.00 = 0,345.50
```

Answer (score 2):

'`#`' is in most languages used as an optional digit, as opposed to '`0`', which is a mandatory digit (to be used to get leading/trailing zeroes).